# SSL Boards and I/Os

Tags: console

Hi Everyone,

I know the name SSL from my music studio days, and it's synonomous with sonic quality and high end gear.  I've recently been looking at it's products for Post-production.

I'm wondering if anyone here has worked with any of the XL-Logic I/Os, Pro-Converts, and/or Mixing Consoles (Matrix, C200, C300).

If you have, what do you think of it? how's the workflow, how well does it work with your DAW, etc (especialy if your using Nuendo)?  How does it feel at your finger tips?

Any feed back would be great.

Thanks.